# Binding radio buttons and textbox based on multiple criteria

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm new to WPF and MVVM, I'm looking for pointers in the right direction.

I'd like to implement something similar to the "print n pages, current page or selection" in Microsoft word.

[image: Microsoft Word Print n pages]

In my example I have radios buttons to switch between *radio1* or *radio2* but also

1. Default to whatever the TimeType in the view model is

   1. `TimeType == Type1` => radio1 is selected, text1 = ""
   2. `TimeType == Type2` => radio2 is selected, text1 = ViewModel.Time
2. If the user **selects** *radio1* I want to clear *text1*.
3. If the **enter a value** in *text1* I'd like the radio buttons to switch to *radio2* and the view model to update accordingly

I have seen and tried various examples of converters but I can't work out how to get the various influences on the behaviour to play nicely together.

I have a feeling that I should be implementing something in the view Model to do the logic but I can't see what to bind to.

XAML

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <local:EnumToBooleanConverter x:Key="e2b" />
</Grid.Resources>
<RadioButton Name="radio1" GroupName="g1" Content="Radio 1"
    IsChecked="{Binding Path=TimeType, Converter={StaticResource e2b}, ConverterParameter={x:Static vm:TimeType.Type1}}"
    />
<RadioButton Name="radio2" GroupName="g1">
    <TextBox Name="text1"
        Text="{Binding Path=ExplicitTime, Mode=TwoWay}">
    </TextBox>
</RadioButton>
```

View Model

```
// UPDATE: added INotifyPropertyChanged as per my actual code
class MagicTimeViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public enum TimeType{Type1, Type2}
    TimeType _type; int _time;
    public TimeType TimeType{
        get{_return _type;}
        set {_type = value; Notify("TimeType");}
    }
    public int Time {
        get{_return _time;}
        set {_time = value; Notify("Time");}
    }
    void Notify(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in you `ViewModel`

Answer (score 0):

Typically to do something like this I use a `ListBox` (since you want to track a selected item, and only one item can be selected at a time), and overwrite the style to display as `RadioButtons`

```
<Style x:Key="RadioButtonListBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation" Value="Cycle" />
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2, 2, 2, 0" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border Background="Transparent">
                                <RadioButton IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="false" 
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding ContentPresenter.Content}"  
                                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The `ViewModel` stores the `SelectedIndex` and `TimeText` properties, and when one property changes, it also updates any related properties.

For example, when `SelectedIndex` changes to 0, clear `TimeText`. When `TimeText` changes, set `SelectedIndex` to 1

Here's an example of the XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox"
         Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonListBoxStyle}"
         SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">

    <ListBoxItem>All</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Pages" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.TimeText, ElementName=MyListBox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. If I've understood correctly the VM exposes the Time value as a string and the selected index as an int. The selected index maps to the 'radio' button to select